# How to pass username and Password in the Socket.Connect In C# TCP/IP

Tags: c#, sockets, authentication, tcp, tcplistener

I have a machine to which i need to be connected to retrieve the data into the text file.For this I have the Ip address,Port number,Username,password of the machine .Now i am trying to connect to the machine but i am not getting where to pass the username and password of the machine to be connected in my c# code.

Please help me.

Comment: This is a matter of the actual service that runs at that very port.

Comment: TCP/IP is just a protocol. Kinda like a telephone... as long as we don't know who's listening on the other side, it's hard to tell which language he will understand. That's not dependent on the brand of phone you use.

Comment: You are only showing a plain TCP connection. This connection is just a pipe where you can send stuff to the server and receive stuff the server sends to you. There is no definition of authentication concepts in TCP and thus, not really a standard way. Put simply: Authentication depends on how the server wants your authentication.

Comment: @StefanWinkler Server wants the authentication using username and password for the service data that i need to capture

Comment: TCP is on OSI Layer 4, user authentication is on Levels 5 and above... For more information about the OSI Layers see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already give the answer, but to summarize:

- For the TCP protocol, it only matters how to connect A and B to enable data transport.
- Anything beyond successful connection is a matter of the inner application protocol that you use
- You need the description of the service and what to send and receive
- You started with your greeting message "Client here". Thats the way how to also transmit user name & pasword I assume.
- For example it could be that after your "Client here" message the server will respond with "User?" and you will have to send the username. Then maybe "Pass?" and you will reply with pass. But this is up to the developer of the server part

Good luck & BR Florian